# Вызов свойств объектов из массива или объекта с параметрами (JS)

Tags: javascript, jquery, объекты, функции

Допустим у нас есть несколько объектов:

```
$.Nav = {
    init: function(){
        return this;
    },

    begin: function(){
        alert('begin nav');
    },

    destroy: function(){
        alert('destroy nav');
    }
}

$.Nav2x = {
    init: function(){
        return this;
    },

    begin: function(){
        alert('begin Nav2x');
    },

    destroy: function(){
        alert('destroy Nav2x');
    }
}

$.Nav3x = {
    init: function(){
        return this;
    },

    begin: function(){
        alert('begin Nav3x');
    },

    destroy: function(){
        alert('destroy Nav3x');
    }
}
```

Есть строка с параметрами в которой говорится какие объекты будут запускаться:

```
var params = {"Nav3x","Nav2x"}
```

И где-то дальше есть функции которые управляют объектами переданными в params:

```
function toDo(){
    //тут должны вызваться методы "begin" всех объектов
    //которые есть в params
}

function toStop(){
    //тут должны вызваться методы "destroy" всех объектов
    //которые есть в params
}
```

Каким образом можно реализовать тела функций toDo() и toStop() ?

Comment: ```var params = {"Nav3x","Nav2x"}``` - это синтаксически неверно

Comment: да, я забыл что еще можно будет чтото передать в функцию

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В цикле вызываете метод `begin`, обращаясь к нужному свойству объекта через [ ]-нотацию.

```
function toDo(object, params){
    params.forEach(function(v){object[v].begin()});
}

// вызов
toDo($, ["Nav3x","Nav2x"])
```

Comment: спасибо, сейчас попробую

Comment: А можно сделать как-то так чтоб в эти же begin и destroy передавать какие-то параметры?